# Why is a blank auto-magically added to an option value of a function in the WL file of a paclet?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, packages, paclets

This is an observation I made during the course of writing a Paclet. The following is an example of a function which happens to use a function from the IGraphM package, whose use is *affected* by the problem, but not caused by IGraphM.

```
  FOObefore[G_Graph, r_List] := Module[{res},
  res = IGraphM`IGLayoutReingoldTilford[G, "RootVertices" -> r, 
    VertexLabels -> 
     VertexLabels -> (v_ :> PropertyValue[{G, v}, "OriginalVertex"])];
  res
  ]
```

It performs as expected:

```
  g = Graph[{a -> b, b -> c, a -> d}];

  {Annotate[#, VertexLabels -> "Name"] &@g, 
 Annotate[#, VertexLabels -> "Name"] &@FOObefore[g, {a}]}
```

[image: Graph and Rooted Graph]

So far so good. After building the Paclet, the function FOObefore does not work anymore as, in fact, in the WL file "RootVertices" became "RootVertices " and "OriginalVertex" became "OriginalVertex " so that I see a "new" function in the WL file of the paclet like this:

```
  FOOafter[G_, r_List] := Module[{res},
  res = IGraphM`IGLayoutReingoldTilford[G, "RootVertices " -> r, 
    VertexLabels -> 
     VertexLabels -> (v_ :> PropertyValue[{G, v}, "OriginalVertex "])];
  res
  ]
```

which gives OptionValue::nodef messages

```
  OptionValue::nodef: Unknown option RootVertices  for {IGLayoutReingoldTilford,Graph}.
```

followed by the graph on the right-hand side of the list of graphs generated by FOObefore.

An easy - though somewhat ugly - work-around is to force strings to stay strings in the WL file by using ToString[*string*] like so:

```
  FOOworking[G_, r_List] := Module[{opt,res},
  opt = ToString["RootVertices"];
  res = IGraphM`IGLayoutReingoldTilford[G, opt -> r, 
    VertexLabels -> 
     VertexLabels -> (v_ :> PropertyValue[{G, v}, ToString["OriginalVertex"]])];
  res
  ]
```

which survives paclet building intact.

I am just curious to know (1) why the blank is added and (2) why no Blank is auto-magically added to "Name" when, for example, I put an annotation on the result before the function returns as in:

```
    FOOafter2[G_, r_List] := 
   Module[{res}, 
    res = IGraphM`IGLayoutReingoldTilford[G, "RootVertices " -> r, 
    VertexLabels -> 
     VertexLabels -> (v_ :> 
        PropertyValue[{G, v}, "OriginalVertex "])];
    Annotate[#, VertexLabels -> "Name"] &@res
    ]
```

I currently use Mathematica 13.2 and Apple M1 Max with Ventura 13.3.1, but have seen this in older versions of Mathematica and previous Apple systems, as well.